# How to trap BEX crash (or any other) error on Atom based tablet PC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tablet-pc

I develop an app on my desktop PC and run on a tablet PC **-Windows 7 32 bit-** then it crashes without any clue, just says application has stopped working.

Are there any lightweight or remote debug possibilities? Or any code injection to handle the crash and report something useful? Tablet PC is slow, just 16GB SSD, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio supports ["remote debugging"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx). You can run your program on your tablet, and debug it with Visual Studio running on your desktop.